# Where does one find the TREC Document format specification?

Tags: parsing, indexing, nlp

I have a bunch of text documents that need to be converted to the TREC format. I have looked around to find if there exists a place where the document format is mentioned or if there are tools which convert documents to this format. The lemur project had the following format :

```
<DOC> 
<DOCNO> document_number </DOCNO> 
<TEXT> 
document text 
</TEXT> 
</DOC>
```

This is mentioned [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lemur/2.0/parsing.html).

Does anybody know if this is the correct format? If not is there a pointer to it?

Answer (score 0):

Lemur on sourceforge confirms the [format](http://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/wiki/Indexer%20File%20Formats/.) for one type of TREC document formats. Else you could try to find and download some of the NIST corpus data mentioned on that [page](http://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/wiki/Indexer%20File%20Formats/.).